# Mysql looping to convert user points

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i've 1 tables called "users", and it's has 4 column, "id,username,point,bonus"
so, it's look like below:

```
+++++++++++++
+   users   +
+++++++++++++
+    id     +
+  username +
+   point   +
+   bonus   +
+++++++++++++
```

each 1 point is worth 0.25 bonus, so if users has 100 point, they got 25 bonus.
how i can convert it from column point to bonus?

i've tried using php looping syntax to select all users data from db, then loop it with simple arithmatic logic. but it's very slow when i try use 1000 users data.
any idea directly from stored procedure? or maybe mysql syntax to loop it?

Comment: Does this work for you: UPDATE `users` SET bonus = point*0.25;

Comment: wow it's works! thanks user2687506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
UPDATE users SET bonus = point*0.25
```

Comment: yeah this is the working code i need.
thank you R.T.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger that automatically updates the "bonus" depending upon the "point". No need to fire update query to manually change the bonus.

You can use it as shown below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "TRIGGERNAME" 
instead of insert  ON "users" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN atomic
DECLARE calc_bonus INTEGER;

if(NEW.point is not null) then
clac_bonus = 0.25 * NEW.point;
Insert into users (id,username,point,bonus) values (NEW.id,NEW.username,NEW.point,calc_bonus);
End if;
END;
```

I hope the above solution helps you :)

Comment: i can't read store procedure syntax since i only use phpmyadmin to create it easily.
but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @pr4mz this is an sql trigger not Procedure which works on insert ie whenever you try to insert any value on "users" table then "bonus" will be calculated automatically, if you use this trigger no need to run update query always after inserting the records in "users" table.